# converting objects to numbers in my dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset containing objects and I wanna convert it to numbers so I can build the model

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to transform it but I have an error, I'm kinda confused, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.get_dummies

```
numerical_data = pd.get_dummies(data)
```